# No se redirecciona mi formulario mvc

Tags: c#, reportviewer, report, rdlc

mi consulta es , estoy tratando de descargar un  rdlc en formato .pdf y logro descargarlo pero no me redirecciona la la pagina que sigue

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

No puedes realizar las dos operaciones cuando el `Response` es un solo, o envias el pdf o redireciona.

Lo que tienes que hace es lanzar la llamada que genera el pdf en una `ventana popup` usando

```
window.open('url reporte');
```

esto es javascript

Entonces en esa ventana tendras el `Response` que envie el pdf con el `BinaryWrite()` y produce la descarga

Mientras por otro lado realizas el submit al action que realiza el `RedirectToAction()` asi tendras dos llamadas y cada una con su `Response` separado.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta Leandro , otra  forma de poder generar el pdf  , ya que no puedo abrir un popup , también estoy pasando parámetros  , gracias por tu respuesta

Comment: no hay otra forma, necesitas tener la respuesta de dos Response separados, un envia el pdf, el otro redireciona. Por supuesto el popup del pdf al generar la descarga se deberia cerrar solo